# Update SharePoint metadata from C# / Visual Studio

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, metadata, office365api

What is an easy way to update metadata in SharePoint via code?

Example: My documents in SharePoint have a dropdown "Project", and I need to set a value for each imported file, based on data from a CSV file.

Should I use:

- REST API
- PowerShell
- DLLs (...using Microsoft.SharePoint)
- Other?

Comment: If you are looking for the easiest no-stress-at-all way, well then i believe that your path should come across Power Automate. You could in theory parse the CSV and just apply a for each loop on the parsed items. A similar way is shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXdeg_6Lr3o
But, to be clear, the only reason i suggest Power Automate is because you wrote "an easy way", meaning that you wont have to deal with authentication protocols or anything, just straight logic behind the updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use [PnP.Powershell](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Set-PnPListItem.html)

For .NET app, if You don't have experience with SharePoint, I would go with [PnP.Core SDK](https://pnp.github.io/pnpcore/using-the-sdk/listitems-intro.html#updating-list-items).

If You are looking for performance, SharePoint REST API should be the fastest, but it requires some knowledge of authentication model and SharePoint API itself.

Hope that will help.